# Fixing x-axis and y-axis in a log plot python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want the x-axis and y-axis from

[image: Plot 1]

to look like the ones on

[image: Plot 2]

The code below is from the python script that I am using to display the data. I am using python 3.9.5.

The log axes are displaying like this `[1x10^-4,  2x10^-4]` and I want them to look like `[1, 2] x 10^-4`.

```
plt.figure(1) 
plt.plot( timeA, testA, label='P' )  
plt.plot( timeA, meanA, label='meanP')
plt.legend() 
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('P') 
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  ´´´ Axes.set_yscale ´´´ method , with this method,  you can change the scale after the Axes is created.

Try to use this:
´´´
ax.set_yscale('log')

´´´

Answer (score 0):

Use ScalarFormatter to control the exponential display and change the tick settings. See this page for more [information](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/scalarformatter.html).

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

x = np.linspace(620000,680000,200)
step = np.random.choice([-1500,1500],200)
y = np.cumsum(step)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y, label='P' )  
ax.plot(x, [np.mean(y)]*len(y), label='meanP')
ax.legend() 
ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.set_ylabel('P') 

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True))
ax.ticklabel_format(style="sci",  axis="both", scilimits=(0,0))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce your example you do not need to use log scales, you need scientific notation for the axis' ticks (more info on [matplotlib's doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html)):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

time = np.linspace(6e-4,7e-4,200)
y = np.random.rand(200)*1e4

plt.figure(1) 
plt.plot(time, y, 'r',label='P' )  
plt.axhline( y=np.mean(y), label='meanP')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('P')

plt.ticklabel_format(
    style='sci',
    axis='x', # x, y or both
    scilimits=(-1,1), # to force it scientific notation
    useOffset=True, # to use offset text with the exponent
    useMathText=True, # to make it 'x 10^n' instead of '1en'
    )
```

[image: Graph with the desired tick label format]